# Is it appropriate to ask for test case ideas?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it considered appropriate to describe a system and then ask for test cases ideas?

The test case ideas could for example include but wouldn't be limited to: naive ideas based on the system description, API/language warnings (eg "I see you're using *that* library, watch out for *this* thing that drove me crazy"), etc.

I bet the experienced programmers on Stack Overflow (or also Software Quality Assurance & Testing) could come up with very interesting insight. However I feel like this sort of question would not match the Q&A format of Stack Exchange.

> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

In that case, a useful answer would be a non exhaustive list of ideas that might break things down. It is a bit unclear to me as whether this sort of question would lead to an answer (interesting input) or a discussion (as it cannot be definitely answered). Also, would you feel like I'm asking you to do my job for me?

Comment: Sounds like you've done a pretty good job of explaining why it doesn't belong here already.  What do you need us for?

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes? :)

Comment: @7hibault: [Voting on meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Here, votes are cast to express (dis)agreement with a post.

Comment: @Servy Well, because it might not match the *current* format of SE but I feel like this sort of question could allow programmers to benefit from the experience of others. Which I think is the original goal of SO?

Comment: The goal of SO is to provide a database of good, quality questions and answers, related to _specific_ problems. Your suggestions would open up a whole category of questions that are simply too broad.

Comment: @7hibault Then why did you ask if such questions are appropriate given the current standards, if you already knew the answer?  As to the goal of SO, it was specifically designed to *not* have these types of discussions.  The site was designed to specifically inhibit those types of questions because the site founders found them to be extraordinarily noisy, and not particularly useful, so they created a place that wouldn't have those types of questions, and would instead of clear, well defined questions with objective answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus First, thank for the voting explanation. Second, that sounds fair enough. Such discussions should then be held on the chat, or simply somewhere else.

Comment: @Servy Because things are not set in stone forever, my mind wasn't made up on that particular point and opening up a discussion about it is a way to submit that to the community. The latter has made it pretty clear that it would only create noise that wouldn't be beneficial for the site overall. Which I couldn't see clearly being blinded by my point of view of "that could help the individual person who would ask the question".

Answer (score 5):

A question like this would be all but certain to turn into a ["list of things"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124489/159251), which is a result that fits poorly into the SE format, as you fear. No one complete answer is likely to emerge; we'll just have a page of one-or-three-item posts, each with merit, but with no good way to judge between them and thus no meaningful way to vote or sort them.

(We do this on Metas occasionally, e.g. [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/). You can see how the answers there are pretty much useless for anyone but the author of the question, who's using them as a bug list.)

This does strike me as a format mismatch that [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) already deals with to some extent, however. One thing they wrestle(d) with is [which answer to accept](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/which-answer-to-accept?rq=1). It might be worth your time to post this proposal about test case "brainstorming" on the Code Review Meta, to see whether the users there would be interested in this sort of question. They might be willing to see them in a slightly altered form that would still get you the results you need.

Comment: Both a List of Things, and also "support" if you ask me. I mean the question is not how to write test cases, I hope if you design and build a system you can come up with at least a good number of good ones. The question then becomes: "Can you come up with test cases I didn't think about?" -> support, without any real clear finish line. That's more the territory of hiring a firm that specializes in software auditing and testing.